# I am having trouble building a responsive layout for a nested column in boot strap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following layout which I put together on figma:[image: view port showing nested column images]

So far I have set up the following grid for the layout:

```html
<div class="container-fluid"> 
  <div class="row" id="sobre-nos-wrapper">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <h1>Title</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <p>
              Text 1
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <p>
             Text 2
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <p>
             text 3
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <img class ="" src="" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like my extra large and large(>= 992px) to display the design above in one viewport, for medium (>= 678) to display just the text in one whole viewport and for small and extra small (>576) to display all elements separately in entire view ports (title, individual paragraphs, and picture). Any help and or advice will be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: `<div class="container-fluid"` add the right angle bracket on the top line `>`

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Do you think this nested setup is in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick crack at it. I hope this gets you pointed in the right direction:

```
<div class="container-fluid"> 
         <div class="row" id="sobre-nos-wrapper">
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1>Title</h1>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p>Text 1</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>Text 2</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <p>text 3</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
            <img class ="" src="" alt="">img
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much @jk!  I just gave it a try and it worked out. I have to do some changes but it should get me going.